# Running Solr on AWS M4.Large (SSD) without SWAP

Tags: linux, ssd, amazon-ec2

I'm running Solr on an AWS EC2 M4.Large (SSD disk) instance with no SWAP. Lately the OOM killer has terminated Solr during periods of high intensity due to lack of available memory.

I have other similar instances on the M3 generation with SWAP without this issue.

I'm wondering what the best practice approach is to avoid this problem going forward. Should I setup SWAP even though it's an SSD disk which I'm reading should not have that. Or is there another preferred way of going about this issue?

Many thanks!

Comment: Well you need more memory, the fact it's a SSD is irrelevant in this respect.

If you can allocate more memory some how, you'll need to do this.

Comment: "hould I setup SWAP even though it's an SSD disk " - You either need a swap or more system memory.